# Vertically align toolshelf

Tags: interface, source-code

I want to vertically align the toolshelf, so the main UI looks that way:

[image: Toolshelf vertically aligned with Photoshop]

If you noticed, I've already moved the navigation gizmo and associated buttons, but I've been digging into the source code and I couldn't find any clue about where is the toolshelf's position defined.

Any help would be welcome, thanks.

Comment: Concretly what is the purpose of this question? Only centering the toolshelf? if yes why?

Comment: Yes, only centering it. I'm developing an addon that adds an upper full-width bar, and it overlaps with the toolshelf.